# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Worldbuilding's [first moderator election](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 4 new moderators are:

[image: HDE 226868] [image: Monica Cellio] [image: Tim B] [image: Serban Tanasa]

They will become your [moderator team](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly. Please thank them for volunteering!

Also, please join me in thanking [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent) and [Michael Kjörling](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/29/michael-kj%c3%b6rling) who served as moderators *pro tempore* and did so much to help this community thrive.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4895722432364544/0).

You can learn more about the new team by reading their [group interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-the-moderators-6fe9d7119fd1#.dibvcg8t5) on the blog.

Comment: Well, there goes my diamond. Good luck to the elected team; the site certainly could do worse.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling thanks again, you did good work.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling shame to see you go, but the ones that got elected look OK to me ;)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If it's any comfort, I voted for you in the election! Anyway, thanks again for the work you did.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I voted for you as well. You did good.

Comment: Thanks to the previous moderators and looking forward to the upcoming ones.

Comment: Congrats HDE 26868, I knew you could do it.

Comment: Congrats to the new moderators!

Comment: Very pleasing to see that all the 3 people I voted for, got elected //(-_-)\\. I just couldn't find the time to read the long answers by some of the more learned candidates and voted for the candidates who provided short, direct answers to the questions -.-

Answer (score 27):

Thank you @MichaelKjörling and @Vincent for your excellent moderation during the beta and early graduation!

Comment: I'd like to second that message, thanks to both of them :)

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3182/28) for a much more detailed account of their excellent contributions.

Comment: Yay Monica! I voted for you, but I just now realized that I hadn't heard anything about the results, so I decided to check it out - congrats!  You're one of my favorite SE people, and WB couldn't ask for a better mod.

Comment: Thanks @WadCheber.  I appreciate the vote of confidence.

Answer (score 14):

### Congrats to the new moderators team. I am sure you will make a great job!

On a personal note, I am glad I took part in the election, and it was really a good mood going around the chat. Many great candidates.

<sub>And by the way, thanks to those who voted for me both in the primary and in the final part</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations to the new moderators.  I may not have been elected, but at least I can rest assured that moderation of the site is in better hands than mine - not that I would have been *bad*, mind you...

Comment: We had a very strong set of candidates.  I think everybody who was on the final ballot, and a couple more besides, would have been fine.

Answer (score 6):

As any of the [Worldbuilding chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat) users could tell you, the election was very intense. In a good way. A large part of the candidates were spending more than 10 hours every day connected. The very first election of the site was very interesting, and curious to the worldbuilders that we are.

Anyway, long story short, we collected some statistics from the election, which I put together in a post for our [blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory):

[Democracy Building in the Worldbuilding World](https://medium.com/universe-factory/democracy-building-in-the-worldbuilding-world-1a4ad92852a9#.utug1gr57)

The whole process of the election is presented as well as some details on the votes attendance and results. Probably a great way to understand how elections works on Stack Exchange and how our great new team got to be elected.

If you have any question, do ask them here, or on chat, or directly on medium.

Comment: Thanks for your work on this!  Interesting reading.

Answer (score 4):

**Hi guys, thank you for the fantastic job you will do and you have done!!!**.

Misters and misses moderators, welcome and thanks. We have elected you because we thought you will do the work well  with responsability.Know you'll do a fantastic job.

@Michael Kjorling, @Vincent, thank you very much for what you've done. A full year has passed and you worked much and well. Let's take a rest.

Answer (score 1):

===Congrats on moderator, all!===

Happy to have been with you through the election process, and participating in the chat. Go out and make us proud!

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations!

May the the odds forever be in your favor...