# Happy second birthday!

Tags: discussion

So today, [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) celebrates its second birthday.

Our second year is over... and what a year!

- We received our [official graduation anouncement](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/congratulations-worldbuilding-is-graduating) in November.
- We got [a](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design?noredirect=1&lq=1) [new](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/worldbuilding-site-design-updates-march-15?rq=1) [design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/site-design-launched?rq=1) finally launched in April.
- We had our first [moderator election](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/2016-community-moderator-election-results), with Monica, Tim, HDE and Serban forming the dream team.
- We changed the [name](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/what-should-the-name-of-our-chat-be) of our chat.
- A [blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory) and a [podcast](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/a-worldbuiding-podcast-youtube-channel) run by the [community](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory).

And of course, many more [questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions) and answers, many discussions on the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor), many new and very active [members](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users).

And of course, new worlds created, expanded, corrected...

---

[Last year](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2617/one-year-of-building-worlds), I suggested to celebrate our first anniversary by citing questions and/or answer that were noticeable.

I think this is a good exercise, as it allows people to remember great posts, or discovering them.

But, this year, let's extend it a bit.

**What would you remember from the second year of Worlbuilding?**

It can be a question, an answer, an event related to the community, some discussions, etc.

Just to avoid too long lists, please limit yourself to a single item per answer, and no more than 2 answers per user, to also give a chance to the others.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the main event of that second year, was of course,

#### The graduation of the beta site to a full-fledged site within the network.

It clearly shows the vision of the site creators, and rewarded the effort of the thriving community.

Answer (score 4):

For me, all those funny comments (and sometimes posts), that are part of almost every good question :) Example:

A comment on the post [How would Facebook Sysadmins prevent the summoning of Cthulhu?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/how-would-facebook-sysadmins-prevent-the-summoning-of-cthulhu#)

> Must resist... urge to migrate... to Server Fault.... – Pops♦ Dec 17 '15 at 3:42

Answer (score 4):

Well consider I was practically absent for the first year I only have memories from this year! But the best ones come from chat;

- We had Glarnak, the god of righteous justice
- We admired the Greek god, Justin Trudeau
- We discovered Nex Terran's obsession with Gaston
- We made fun of everything from SJW's to English
- We renamed the chat and created a podcast!
- We saw the death of the Fortnighly topic challenge and the birth of
  Anatomically Correct.

I have loved the last year and cannot wait for another great year with the Mad engineers and Bewildered gods of Worldbuilding Stack Exchanges

Answer (score 3):

For me the main thing is being a candidate in an election (for anything) for the first time ever. I particularly remember seeing the platforms for all the candidates then people hanging around in chat writing jqueries to track results as they were coming in.

After that the next thing is the site graduation, which is a big achievement that we've all worked towards.